# Can I securely trash a folder that contains applications without ruining the applications on my HD?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, trash

I get a dialogue box asking if I want to leave or trash associated files as I am trashing an application. The folder in question is a duplicate of one I have saved in Documents. The applications are cloned via carbon copy cloner from old to new iMac, I wanted to save old versions, and the current applications (same ones as in applications folder in finder) are in the folder, too. They all launch fine from documents folder, surprisingly. I'm afraid that if I securely empty the trash containing this folder,it will affect all of my applications installed in the normal way in the applications folder on the HD. 
(Adobe CS5 Creative Suite for example)
Mac OSX 10.7.3
Advice appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the file(s) you are wanting to securely delete are already in the Trash(and everything works as you like), you will be ok securely deleting them from the Trash. I would leave the associated files, as you can go and manually trash those as you need to and this will not risk the computer trashing something you actually wanted by mistake. Better to error on the side of caution. ***As always, make sure you have a good backup of your files. This way if something goes horribly wrong, you're covered.***